# Word for someone who isn't detail-oriented

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

I am pretty sure I have seen a word for someone who often misses small details, but it has slipped out of my mind. Any ideas?

Comment: On this post: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/68909/18655, I had an answer that explained the word *careless*. I think it would suit your situation as well.

Comment: If you weren't so *scatterbrained* you'd remember it.

Comment: If the problem is that the person works quickly but tends to omit details that (some) others consider important, the word _slapdash_ might apply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked up "observant," the antonym at [thesaurus.com](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/observant) and there seem to be no suitable adjectives without a negating prefix, but "unobservant" or "imperceptive" might fit.

Answer (score 1):

Sloppy comes to mind. When I looked up synonyms for that and antonyms for meticulous I found imprecise, superficial, negligent and unthorough (although Word does show the last one as misspelled for some reason). Was that what you were aiming for?

Answer (score 1):

The opposite of detail oriented is 'visionary', that is, if you want to focus on the positive connotations of someone that looks at the big picture.
If you are looking to focus on the negatives, then you might want to go with careless or thoughtless. 
If you wanted a word that points out the negatives of someone with great attention to detail you could go with 'anal retentive'.

Comment: Your answer is covering all bases for us, but it would benefit from linked references to authoritative sources.